# Twitter api, get current authenticated user info

Tags: c#, api, twitter

I cannot find the call which returns info for the current authenticated oauth user :s Im writing a mall app which allows the user to carry out follow tasks but cannot find an api call that returns info of the person authenticated.

Anyone know how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [verify_credentials](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/account/verify_credentials):

> Returns an HTTP 200 OK response code and a representation of the requesting user if authentication was successful; returns a 401 status code and an error message if not. Use this method to test if supplied user credentials are valid.